# make a template function that distinguishes value from predicate

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I would like to have a template function `contains` which has two possible definitions, depending on the second type:

```
template <typename ElementType, typename CollectionType>
bool contains(const CollectionType & collection, ElementType element)
{
    return collection.end() != std::find(collection.begin(), collection.end(), element);
}
```

and

```
template <typename CollectionType, typename PredicateType>
bool contains(const CollectionType & collection, PredicateType predicate)
{
    return collection.end() != std::find_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(), predicate);
}
```

The standard library often uses _if to distinguish predicate from value versions of algorithms - such as `find` and `find_if`.

Ideally, I'd like the compiler to figure out which one to use.  After all, the above two templates are intended for very different uses - the types of ElementType and PredicateType are pretty different domains.

Is there a good way to accomplish this via template shenanigans?  Or am I stuck with finding two different names for the above contains functions?

Comment: What if your container contains predicates?

Comment: Good point.  Perhaps this cannot be solved without an explicit difference in names.

Comment: Not sure but using `std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<ElementType, typename CollectionType::value_type>, ElementType>::type` as the `ElementType` in the first case may remove ambiguity.

Comment: There's got to be a way to come at it from detecting if it is a predicate - i.e. a callable entity... when I have a moment, I'll see if I can make headway from that angle...

Answer (score 4):

If your containers play nice and define member `value_type`s, then you could make the "element" overload more specific:

```
template <typename C>
bool contains(C const & collection, typename C::value_type const & element);

template <typename C, typename P>
bool contains(C const & collection, P predicate);
```

More arcane approaches might be checking if the container defines `begin`/`end` functions and deriving the element type from those. In general it's fairly tricky to decide whether a given type is a container...

Comment: This sort of approach always almost works for me.  Too often I find that I'm trying to detect if a collection contains something that is comparable, but isn't the exact type contained.  Hence it tries to resolve to the second template, and fails.  :(

Comment: @Mordachai: The [pretty printer code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) tries to be a bit more clever about what's a container, if that's any help...